# Radius of Newton's rings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, interference

I had a question about finding the radius for bright Newton's rings. According to Wikipedia the final answer should be

$$ r = \sqrt{\lambda R\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)} $$

where $R$ is the radius of curvature and $N$ is a whole number starting from 0. When I was deriving the equation, I end up with:

$$ r = \sqrt{\lambda R\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right) - d^2} $$

where $d$ is the distance from the edge of the circle to the ground. I looked it up, and [this](http://physical-optics.blogspot.com/2011/06/newtons-rings.html) says that $d^2$ can be ignored because $d$ is small.

My question is, what is the basis for concluding that $d$ is small? Are there cases where this is not true?

Answer (score 2):

In the derivation of the formula for the radius of a ring the intersecting chord theorem, Pythagoras , etc is used to show that $r^2= 2Rt -t^2 = t(2R-t)$ where $t$, your $d$, is the distance between the top of the bottom surface and the bottom of the lens surface.

[image]

The radius of curvature of the surface of the lens $R$ might be $1.00\, \rm m$ and $t$ would be a few wavelengths of light, say $10^{-6}\, \rm m $.

So $2R-t = 2\times 1.00 - 10^{-6} \approx 2.00$ to a very good approximation.

It is unlikely that the radius of curvature of the surface of the lens will be comparable to the wavelength of light.